# $().live(function(){}); and jQuery.browser is undefined in jquery 1.9.0

Tags: jquery

`$().live(function(){});` and `jQuery.browser` is `undefined` in jQuery 1.9.0

If I user jQuery 1.8.3 instead of jquery 1.9.0 it is working fine in my project.

And what are the functions undefined and why?

Comment: You would have noticed by reading the release notes for 1.9

Comment: was documented in the release notes: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/

Comment: i did not noticed the release notes for 1.9. i am use nuget in my project it has replace old jquery to new and changed the file path. i noticed bug in firebug it was undefined.

Comment: In my project plugins need jQuery.browser. so that it is not working...

Comment: move back to your old jquery version..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please read the [jQuery upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/), in 1.9 release they have removed all the deprecated methods from previous releases. But they have provided a migration plugin to help the developers during the migration period.

The [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was deprecated in v1.7.0 in favour of [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), please use this in your code.

You can include the [migrate plugin](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js)

Comment: i can use jquery-1.9.0 by adding migrate plugin also. so that it will work?

Comment: yes, But I wouldn't recommend it for new code. it is very easy to convert them

Comment: k.. many jquery plugins are compressed file. so that only it is unable convert them...

Comment: any site or software is there for converting compressed min file to normal file js and vise versa?

Comment: Ok, if there are third party plugin dependencies, it is better to use the migration plugin for the time being

Answer (score 2):

The live function is deprecate you have to use `on` instead of `live`

Answer (score 2):

`.live()` has been removed: http://api.jquery.com/live/. Use `.on()` instead: http://api.jquery.com/on/:

`.browser()` has been removed as well: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Answer (score 1):

These functions are deprecated in jquery 1.9.0

Answer (score 1):

Because they are deprecated!

instead of `.live()` you should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**jQuery.browser**

Returns: PlainObjectversion deprecated: 1.3, removed: 1.9

Description: Contains flags for the useragent, read from navigator.userAgent. We recommend against using this property; please try to use feature detection instead (see jQuery.support). jQuery.browser may be moved to a plugin in a future release of jQuery.