# TypeError: $.browser is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-blockui

I am using msdropdown image combo box to create dropdown select options.
when I run this code locally on my PC, everything works great. But when I run it on GoDaddy servers, the msdropdown becomes disabled.

It doesn't work on any browsers. Firebug displays the error as:

```
TypeError: $.browser is undefined

 echo <<<_START
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <title>profile</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="generator" content="HAPedit 3.1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="profile.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dd.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="javascript/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/drop.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.dd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.blockUI3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/req.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/body.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', minDate: 0, maxDate: "+0M +5D"
 });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        function otherSelect() {
            var other = document.getElementById("otherBox");
            if    (document.getElementById("form3").place.options[document.getElementById("form3").place.selectedIndex].value == "other") {
                other.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
            else {
                other.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }
    //-->
</script>
</head>

<body id="body">

 <div id="container">
<div class="header">
<a href="profile.php" class="logo">
    <img title="Title" alt="Alter" src="images/logo.png" border="0" height="60px"  width="200px">
</a>
<a style="text-decoration:none; margin-top:15px; font-family:Bookman Old Style;  font-size:12px; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold;" href="logout.php?id='$session_id'"  class="req">
Logout
</a>
<a href="notification.php?email='$encrypted_string'" class="req1">
<img border="0" title="Notifications" alt="Notifications" src="images/notification.png" height="60px" width="60px"><div class="text1">$numbr</div>
</a>
<a href="request.php?email='$encrypted_string'" class="req2">
<img border="0" title="requests" alt="Requests" src="images/request.png" height="60px" width="60px"><div class="text">$req</div>
</a>
</div>

<div id="navigation">
<div id="picture"><img src="$img">
<h1 id="display" style="margin-left:30px;">$name</h1><hr>
<table style="background-color:#81F781;font-family:Chaparral Pro,corbel; font-   size:17px; color:#1C1C1C; width:100%;" border="1" cellpadding="25">
<tr><th>Requests($n)</th></tr></table>
</div>
</div></div>
<div style="margin-top: 90px;" id="conte">

_START;

 echo <<<_START
 </div>
 <div id="accept" style="display:none">
<form method="post" id="form3" action="cnfrm.php">
<br><table border="0" style="width:100%;" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4"><tr>    <td  style="font-family:Chaparral Pro,corbel; font-size:17px; color:#1C1C1C;">Meeting Date:   <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date"/></td>
<td style="font-family:Chaparral Pro,corbel; font-size:17px; color:#1C1C1C;">@ about<input  type="text" id="time" size="3">AM<input type="radio" name="time2" id="time2" value="am"> |   PM<input type="radio" name="time2" id="time2" value="pm"></td></tr>
_START;

echo <<<H
<tr><td valign="top" rowspan="2">
<select id="place" name="place" style="width:300px;" onchange="otherSelect()">
    <option value="" data-description="Choose your meeting place"  selected="selected">Meet me @</option>
    <option value="LC" data-image="image/msdropdown/icons/meet.png" data-description="Limbdi Corner">L.C</option>
    <option value="VT" data-image="image/msdropdown/icons/meet.png" data-description="Vishwanath temple">V.T</option>
    <option value="H.G" data-image="image/msdropdown/icons/meet.png" data-description="Hyderabaad Gate">H.G</option>
    <option value="D.G Corner" data-image="image/msdropdown/icons/meet.png" data-description="Dhanrajgiri Corner">D.G corner</option>
    <option value="Library" data-image="image/msdropdown/icons/meet.png" data-description="IIT Library">Library</option>
    <option value="other" data-image="image/msdropdown/icons/meet.png" data-description="Add your own...">Other place</option>
</select> </td></tr>
H;
```

This problem has been solved:[msdropdown update](https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown) and download the latest files.

Comment: what version of jquery are you using

Comment: OP your code doesn't seem to have `$.browser` in it, so I assume its in one of your plugins.

Comment: jquery 1.9.0...however i shifted to JQuery 1.8.3 just for test purpose. Now the error is not shown. But still the dropdown is disabled

Comment: I just inserted this script too: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 156):

just put the $.browser code in your js

```
var matched, browser;

jQuery.uaMatch = function( ua ) {
    ua = ua.toLowerCase();

    var match = /(chrome)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
        /(webkit)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
        /(opera)(?:.*version|)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
        /(msie) ([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
        ua.indexOf("compatible") < 0 && /(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+)|)/.exec( ua ) ||
        [];

    return {
        browser: match[ 1 ] || "",
        version: match[ 2 ] || "0"
    };
};

matched = jQuery.uaMatch( navigator.userAgent );
browser = {};

if ( matched.browser ) {
    browser[ matched.browser ] = true;
    browser.version = matched.version;
}

// Chrome is Webkit, but Webkit is also Safari.
if ( browser.chrome ) {
    browser.webkit = true;
} else if ( browser.webkit ) {
    browser.safari = true;
}

jQuery.browser = browser;
```

Comment: jQuery.browser (or $.browser) has been deprecated since version 1.3 and has been removed since version 1.9. This fix works for me though!

Comment: I don't know from where you got this idea and the code, but it saves my life. Thank you for the great mind!!!

Comment: @iyal this code comes from an older version of http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js

Comment: Thanks, this is significantly better than loading an entire library just for one function.

Answer (score 46):

`$.browser` has been removed from JQuery 1.9. You can to use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) project instead

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed

**UPDATE TO SUPPORT IE 10 AND IE 11 (TRIDENT version)**

To complete the @daniel.moura answer, here is a **version which support IE 11 and +**

```
var matched, browser;

jQuery.uaMatch = function( ua ) {
    ua = ua.toLowerCase();

    var match = /(chrome)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
        /(webkit)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
        /(opera)(?:.*version|)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
        /(msie)[\s?]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||       
        /(trident)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+)|)/.exec( ua ) ||
        ua.indexOf("compatible") < 0 && /(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+)|)/.exec( ua ) ||
        [];

    return {
        browser: match[ 1 ] || "",
        version: match[ 2 ] || "0"
    };
};

matched = jQuery.uaMatch( navigator.userAgent );
//IE 11+ fix (Trident) 
matched.browser = matched.browser == 'trident' ? 'msie' : matched.browser;
browser = {};

if ( matched.browser ) {
    browser[ matched.browser ] = true;
    browser.version = matched.version;
}

// Chrome is Webkit, but Webkit is also Safari.
if ( browser.chrome ) {
    browser.webkit = true;
} else if ( browser.webkit ) {
    browser.safari = true;
}

jQuery.browser = browser;
// log removed - adds an extra dependency
//log(jQuery.browser)
```

Comment: Or instead of modernizr, possibly question why you need browser sniffing in the first place.

Comment: I added the migrate plugin. But still the problem exists

Comment: The migrate plugin is only useful to detect removed or depreceted functions, it will not fix your problem. What is your JQuery version?

Comment: i shifted to JQuery 1.8.3 just for test purpose. Now the error is not shown. But still the dropdown is disabled

Answer (score 40):

Just include this script

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js

after you include your jquery javascript file.

Answer (score 25):

I placed the following html in my code and this cleared up the $.browser error

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps u

Comment: Worked Like a charm!

Answer (score 8):

Replace your jquery files with followings :

`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you very much. After almost 5-6 hours of trying I fixed my issue with this.

Answer (score 7):

[$().live(function(){}); and jQuery.browser is undefined in jquery 1.9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458511/livefunction-and-jquery-browser-is-undefined-in-jquery-1-9-0)   - $.browser was deprecated in jquery update

sounds like you are using a different version of jquery 1.9 in godaddy so either change your code or include the migrate plugin http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js

Comment: I added the migrate plugin. But still the problem exists

Comment: it's not in the home page... and for logging in, you need a specific domain id. So you wont be able to see the problem

Comment: curious, if you try loading jquery 1.8 http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js , does it fix it, or is it a different issue causing the menu not to load

Comment: I tried using jquery 1.8.3. The error is not shown, however the dropdown still remains disabled

Comment: So its not related to "$.browser is undefined!" looks like you need to look for a different issue for fixing the menu

Answer (score 3):

i did solved it using jQuery migrate link specified below:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere the code--either your code or a jQuery plugin--is calling `$.browser` to get the current browser type.

However, early has year [the `$.browser` function was deprecated](http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/2012/08/14/jquery-1-8-and-browser-detection/). Since then some bugs have been filed against it but because it is deprecated, the jQuery team has decided not to fix them. I've decided not to rely on the function at all.

I don't see any references to `$.browser` in your code, so the problem probably lies in one of your plugins. To find it, look at the source code for each plugin that you've referenced with a `<script>` tag.

As for how to fix it: well, it depends on the context. E.g., maybe there's an updated version of the problematic plugin. Or perhaps you can use another plugin that does something similar but doesn't depend on `$.browser`.

Answer (score 1):

In Wordpress 8.5.1, I installed this plugin "[Enable jQuery Migrate Helper](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/)".

And it worked without any problem.

Comment: I certainly got the error in Wordpress, and your recommended plugin patched the problem. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1):

Since this thread is the first entry most of the people stumble upon. I would like to share my fix as well.
You can enqueue your script as following in functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'patch_jquery_migrate' );
function patch_jquery_migrate() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery-migrate');
    wp_register_script('jquery-migrate', ("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"), false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-migrate' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did solved using this jquery for Github

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>`

Please Refer this link for more info.
https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/issues/469