# Issue with bootstrap-transition.js : Unable to get property 'chrome' of undefined or null reference

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-2

I am getting the following error with bootstrap-transition.js v2.1.1 (which in this case exists as file ucommerce.bootstrap.js):

```
 Unhandled exception at line 1915, column 7 in
 http://localhost:11599/scripts/ucommerce.bootstrap.js

 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get 
 property 'chrome' of undefined or null reference
```

The following are the lines in bootstrap-transition.js which failed, the particular line that failed in the one marked as >>>>>.

, listen: function () {
      this.$element
        .on('blur',     $.proxy(this.blur, this))
        .on('keypress', $.proxy(this.keypress, this))
        .on('keyup',    $.proxy(this.keyup, this))

```
  >>>>>>**if ($.browser.chrome || $.browser.webkit || $.browser.msie) {**
    this.$element.on('keydown', $.proxy(this.keydown, this))
  }
```

I am fairly new to Bootstrap and am not sure how to approach debugging this. Any explanations, solutions or guidance as to how to debug further would be very much appreciated..

Thanks in anticipation
Terry Clancy
ClanceZ

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved ........

I got $.browser is undefined error because jQuery.browser was deprecated in later versions of jQuery.  I  went back to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js  and it fixed the problem.

For more info see

[TypeError: $.browser is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798403/typeerror-browser-is-undefined)

Terry Clancy 
ClanceZ