# "TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function" and "TypeError: $.browser is undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got error like, `TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function`.
So, I include jquery like,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

When I include this api it shows another error like, `TypeError: $.browser is undefined`

I coudn't find solution. Any suggestion?

Comment: Add jquery UI library. refere this https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Maybe you should use the last stable version, jQuery( 1.11.3 ) , jQueryUI( 1.11.4 )

Comment: just check this answer. you need to add browser code http://stackoverflow.com/a/17495060/2006386

Comment: Thanks kaushik, but still got some problem of "TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function".

Answer (score 0):

$.browser is not support in jquery1.9 anymore. You can try $.version.

Answer (score 0):

Sequence is very important , you need to first load/import JQuery and then only Jquery UI. as below :

```
'<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>'
```